# Backbone Relational with TypeScript - findOrCreate not working when using custom idAttribute

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, backbone-relational

When I define a custom idAttribute on my Backbone model, findOrCreate will not work, saying

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate more than one Backbone.RelationalModel
with the same id per type!
```

I think this is a TypeScript issue. I don't know if it's related, but when you create a class with TypeScript and set the idAttribute as below, you will see that the object itself has an explicit "idAttribute" property, which is not the case when you do it in plain javascript;

```
module Application.Models {
    export class Zoo extends Backbone.RelationalModel {
        constructor(options?) {
            this.relations = [{
                type: Backbone.HasMany,
                key: 'animals',
                relatedModel: 'Application.Models.Animal',
                collectionType: 'Application.Models.AnimalCollection',
                reverseRelation: {
                    key: 'livesIn',
                    includeInJSON: 'id'
                }
            }];
            super(options);
        }
    }

    export class Animal extends Backbone.RelationalModel {
        constructor(options?) {
            this.idAttribute = "AnimalId";
            super(options);
        }
    }

    export class AnimalCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
            constructor(options?) {
            super(options);
            this.model = 'Application.Models.Animal';
        }
    }
}

var artis = new Application.Models.Zoo({ name: 'Artis' });
var lion = new Application.Models.Animal({ AnimalId: 123, species: 'Lion', livesIn: artis });

Application.Models.Animal.findOrCreate({ AnimalId: 123 }); // FIRST TIME FINE
Application.Models.Animal.findOrCreate({ AnimalId: 123 }); // SECOND TIME - NOT FINE
```

Answer (score 1):

The idAttribute property should be defined on the prototype. Your code defines idAttribute for every instance of the class.

Depending on what browsers you want to support, you can use a getter method to do this in TypeScript.

```
export class Animal extends Backbone.RelationalModel {
    public get idAttribute () { return 'AnimalId' }
}
```

You can also add it to the class after it is defined using vanilla JavaScript.

```
Animal.prototype.idAttribute = 'AnimalId';
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh. It appears to work if you set idAttribute in initialize instead of the constructor:

```
initialize: function(attributes) {
        this.id = attributes['AnimalId'] || attributes['id'];
      },
```